# Alpine.js x-show stops working when element is made visible with JS

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have a modal that becomes visible via a JS trigger

```
<div x-show="modalVisible" x.on:click.away="modalVisible = false" id="modal">
</div>

document.getElementById("modal").setAttribute("style", "display: show;")
```

The problem I am facing is, if I use JS to make the modal visible x.on:click.away does not make the model hidden.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it modalVisible = false? and not hide or something?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm not by any kind of an expert in JS. Just a noob. So, sorry if I theorize it wrongly.

When you set `element.style.display = "block"` you're **setting** the property of `modalVisible = false` (as opposed to **toggling** the property like `modalVisible = !modalVisible`) as in your `@click.away` expression.

However, you have triggered the Alpine's event listener. Alpine will then continue listening to your `@click.away` event, and set `modalVisible = false` every time you click outside of the component.

I've played with this kind of situation on my Codepen (with some `console.log`s to debug), and **it will work if I set `@click.away ="modalVisible = !modalVisible"`** that toggles the state rather than sets the state like `@click.away = "modalVisible = false"`. I write the property as `show` instead of `modalVisible`:
https://codepen.io/wanahmadfiras/pen/KKNrXOO

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no such thing as `display: show`, you'd have to set the initial display you had, so perhaps `display: block` could work.

AlpineJS has a similar example in their [github repository](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/), so I just adapted it a little to fit your needs.

```
<div id="modal" x-data="{ modalVisible: false }">
  <button @click="modalVisible = true">Open Modal</button>

  <ul x-show="modalVisible" @click.away="modalVisible = false">
    Modal Content
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
My problem is as under.
I have a modal that is triggered via JS. I have changed my JS code to set display="block".
But when I click outside the modal to close it does not close. I have set up Alpine.js on the modal on:click.away="modalVisible = false".
When I let Alpine.js handle making visible and making invisible then it works fine

Comment: I have dug a little deeper into the behaviour of x-show. When the HTML tags display attribute is changed by JS, Alpine.js x-show stops working on that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work using a custom event instead of removing display: none with custom JS.

```
let event = new CustomEvent("modal", {
  detail: {
    items: []
  }
});
window.dispatchEvent(event);

In my HTML I added

x-on:modal.window="modalVisible = true"
```

This works though I still don't know why altering directly with JS does not work.